# Cannot attach UITextField to IBOutlet of type UIControl

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I created this IBOutlet in my custom class

```
@IBOutlet var nextControl: UIControl!
```

I can connect UIButton to it but I cannot connect a UITextField to it, even though both are a subclass of UIControl.

Is there a way to do it? Thanks a lot

Comment: I am able to create a `UITextField` outlet as `UIControl`. Can you mention what issue you are facing?

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to connect a `UITextField` and not a `UITextView` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just write something like this:

```
@IBOutlet var nextControl: UITextField
```

nextControl is the name of your UITextField

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try again. I've created same case as yours and I can connect a `UITextField` to `UIControl` IBOutlet. (See image)

[image]